# RewriteRule not working when I create a sub folder within my /var/www/html

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^home/([\(\)A-Z_-]+) search.php?term=$1 [NC,L]
```

Hi, I am completely new to `htaccess`. I have written
the above `RewriteRule` which is working when I create my project in `html` folder and `htaccess` is present in `html` folder itself. I created a subfolder called `test`, how can I again write the `RewriteRule`?

Thank you:)

Comment: What you want actually? Be more specific about your expected results.

Comment: the rewritten URL is relative, it is resolved according to the documentation. In short: it _is_ working. To have it work in your favor, either make it an absolute result or check the _RewriteBase_ directive. I would strongly assume your question is of duplicate Q&A material, so only leaving a comment first.

Comment: @PrathameshRaut I am changing the url by using RewriteRule, It's not working while I create a sub folder, so how can I again configure for sub folder?

Comment: May be you can add another .htaccess in sub folder